# Track workitem from last updated time

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, devops

I have a program that runs every 2 hours to track workitems.

Here is the code I use to track the workitem every 2 hours.

```
    queryTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ssZ");
    string wiql = $"SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitems WHERE [System.TeamProject]='xxx' AND [System.ChangedDate] > '{queryTime}'";
```

However, sometimes the service for DevOps will be unavailable, so I will miss the workitem that fall inside the time range.

Thus, I save the datetime in a file everytime the program successfully run. So, let's say now the program run at 10AM(query the workitem that have changed 8AM onward) and after it finishes, it will save 10AM in the file. The next time to run the program is 12PM, but the service is down at 12PM so I can't track the workitem that have changed on 10AM onward.

So, next round the program will run at 2PM, it should track the workitem that have changed from 10AM onwards since it missed at 12PM. I use code below to read the last insert time(10AM) that save in the file. Then I lost at here, what should I do to track the workitem that have changed from last insert time? Any suggestion?

```
string query = $"SELECT * FROM WorkItemLastRun ORDER BY LastChangedTime DESC LIMIT 1 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have scheduled your task to run every 2 hours, all you have to do is run the query BETWEEN the last run datetime and the current datetime. So, save the current DateTime in a variable, retrieve the last run datetime, run your query with a BETWEEN

```
currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ssZ");
lastRunDateTime = // get this from your database table 
string wiql = $"SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitems WHERE [System.TeamProject]='xxx' AND [System.ChangedDate] BETWEEN '{lastRunDateTime}' AND '{currentDateTime}'";
```

And then when you are done, save the value of the 'currentDateTime' as your 'lastRunDateTime' value in your table.